# Doctrine How to get result in one row when using addSelect query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this Doctrine query in my SystemRepository :

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('s')
        ->addSelect('item')
        ->from('Item', 'item')
        ->where('item.iId = s.id');
```

With this query, i get results like that :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => System 1
    [1] => ItemObject related to SystemObject 1
    [2] => SystemObject 2
    [3] => ItemObject related to SystemObject 2
    [4] => SystemObject 3
    [5] => ItemObject related to SystemObject 3
)
```

But i would like to get result like that :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array( 
            [0] => SystemObject 1
            [1] => ItemObject related to SystemObject 1
            ),
    [1] => Array( 
            [0] => SystemObject 2
            [1] => ItemObject related to SystemObject 2
            ),
    [2] => Array( 
            [0] => SystemObject 3
            [1] => ItemObject related to SystemObject 3
            )
)
```

Is that possible ?

For technical reasons, i can't make a Doctrine mapping between systemand item.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible out of box. But regardless, those two structures look very similar, in my opinion. You can apply PHP-based grouping easily:

```
$grouped = [];
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($data); $i+=2){
    $grouped[] = [
        $data[$i],
        $data[$i+1]
    ];
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I didn't dare to give this answer, but you're right.

Comment: Hah I know what you mean :D

Answer (score -1):

You can use "getScalarResult" too.

Answer (score -3):

It's not possible out of the box, but You can use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) on result set.

```
$data = Array
(
    'SubscriptionObject 1',
    'PaymentObject related to SubscriptionObject 1',
    'SubscriptionObject 2',
    'PaymentObject related to SubscriptionObject 2',
    'SubscriptionObject 3',
    'PaymentObject related to SubscriptionObject 3'
);

$grouped = array_chunk($data, 2);
var_dump($grouped);
```

No Magic way to change keys, use `array_walk` function after chunking array:

```
array_walk($grouped, function(&$item){
    $item = [
        'subscription' => $item[0],
        'payment' => $item[1]
    ];
    return $item;
});
```